# Express JS API Returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, express

I am new to Javascript and am using Express to make a REST API for the backend of a project I'm working on. However, for some reason, either the API returns undefined or the fetch statement in my main.js file is somehow changing it to be that. Here is the backend code in question:

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use((req, _, next) => {
    console.log(req);
    next();
  });
//setup express.js

//what to do when someone pings us
app.get('/', async (_, res) => {
    res.send({ url:'https://gifdb.com/images/high/you-got-rick-rolled-rick-astley-dance-2s99zcvywfvs3kao.gif' });
});

//start listening
app.listen(8080, () => console.log('http://localhost:8080/'));
```

And here is the code that fetches it:

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/', {
      method: 'GET',
    });


    const { image } = await response.json();

    console.log(image)

    const result = document.querySelector('#result');
    result.innerHTML = `<img src="${image}" width="512" />`;
```

Comment: because there is no key with the name ``image`` in the received JSON. You have ``url`` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `const { image }` is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) which tries to find the `image` property from `await response.json();` which is obviously `undefined`.

The code should be:

```
const image = (await response.json()).url;
console.log(image);
```

**OR**

```
const { url } = await response.json();
console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

On the server, you named the property for the image URL `url`, but on the browser, you're referencing it as `image`. You'll need to change them to match.